# Passing object from Laravel blade to Vue through props transforms number values to string

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, object

I am building a website with bookings and I try to pass an object with available rooms to Vue.
In my local environment (laragon win10), it works fine, numbers are numbers, strings are strings.
[image]

But on the server (shared hosting), some of the numbers turn into strings.
This causes some nasty issues in v-if statements.

[image]

I found a solution using JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK in my return statement, but I am looking for something more permanent to avoid forgetting about this.

[image]

Is there a way to force the server (using php 7.4) to work like my local environment?
Or if not, a way to make my local environment (laragon) behave like the server, so that I am forced to avoid these issues?

Answer (score 0):

To make the 2 environments yeild the same result, you should update PHP version on your local environment (Laragon) to version 7.4:

It is very easy to do it with Laragon. You can follow the tutorial here to see how:
https://forum.laragon.org/topic/166/tutorial-how-to-add-another-php-version-php-7-4-updated

Comment: I switched to PHP 7.3 and it worked fine. It may be some due to some settings on the hosting server.